# Почему не видит пространство имён?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Это пространство имён существует. До этого работало. Но почему-то сломалось.

> Имя "MainViewModel" не существует в пространстве имен
>   "clr-namespace:WpfLocalization".

```
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type localglobalization:MainViewModel}}"

xmlns:localglobalization="clr-namespace:WpfLocalization"
```

Comment: Да да. Такое бывает. Это баги студии. Перезагрузи и выполни сборку. Если не поможет, очисти кэш студии, перезагрузи комп. Мне помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Данный пример демонстрирует подключение пространства имен в `XAML` разметке.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

        // Задаем псевдоним для пространства имен с VM, папка с `ViewModels` расположена в корне проекта
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.ViewModels"

        // Если необходимо подключиться к типам, расположенным в другой сборке
        xmlns:myLibrary="clr-namespace:MyLibrary;assembly=MyLibrary"

        // Настраиваем DataContext для работы в "режиме дизайнера"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mc:Ignorable="d"  
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance localglobalization:MainViewModel}}"  
xmlns:localglobalization="clr-namespace:WpfLocalization"
```

Comment: так не работает